# UISlider maximum track image using minimum track image when slider button crosses approx 60% of max value

Tags: ios, xcode, uislider

I am using UISlider with minimum and maximum images set as follows,

```
UIImage *stetchLeftTrack = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Left.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:14.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
[self._timeSlider setMinimumTrackImage:stetchLeftTrack forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIImage *stetchRightTrack = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Right.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:14.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
[self._timeSlider setMaximumTrackImage:stetchRightTrack forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

[image: Max image using min image]

Everything works as expected untill slider button crosses approx 60% of max value. 
As you can see in screenshot both min and max slider images got set to min images (Left.png).

Please help
Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: what is your question? can't understand.

Comment: My minimumTrackImage (Left.png) is green while maximumTrackImage(Right.png) is of different colour. When my slider is below 60%(approx) of total value left side of slider look green and right side with different color as expected. But when it crosses 60% of total value right side also turns to green (uses Left.png).

Comment: Are you setMinimum value and Maximum value?

Comment: yes setting both and slider button movement working fine..

Comment: have u solved your issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact I think the base of the problem is a different one, and your solution worked because of that.

I had the same problem, and when reading the documentation for the track images again I noticed that the **stretchable images have to be such that the middle (stretchable) part has to be 1 pixel wide** (in retina 2 pixel). My track images were defined as being the complete width of the slider, with left and right caps being 20 pixels, and the middle part something like 230 pixels ...

When I changed the trackable images to be 41 pixels (20 pixel left part, 1 pixel stretchable middle part, 20 pixels right part) and set the cap insets to `UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, 20)`, it worked all fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is bit strange but finally i figured it out..

My Left.png size is 20x6 (green)
And Right.png size was 84x8 (white)

I changed my Right.png size to 20x8 this solved my problem